# Invalid Python Syntax Define Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, syntax-error

```
Satchel = {'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coin': 42, 'dagger': 1}
def displayInventory(inventory, leftWidth, rightWidth):
    print('INVENTORY'.center(leftWidth + rightWidth, '-'))
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        print(k.ljust(leftWidth, '.') + str(v).rjust(rightWidth))
        item_total = int(item_total) + int(v)
        print('Total number of items: ' + str(item_total)

displayInventory(Satchel, 15, 6)
```

I receive a syntax error when I call the displayInventory function. I am having trouble determining what is wrong with this code.

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: Please proofread your code more carefully in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last call to `print` in your function is missing a closing parenthesis. In addition, in the code you are showing you are using the name `item_total` before defining it.

In general: if you get a weird syntax error - look at the previous line.